# float and string with same value, false result in php

Tags: php

this operation

```
$data['can_redeem'] = $data['payments_client']['accumulated']>=floatval($data['charge_limit'])
```

where  `$data['payments_client']['accumulated']` = 7.0 and `$data['charge_limit']` = "7" is giving `false`. It has to be something about the types but  in appearance both variables have the same value.

Comment: try converting both to int forst

Comment: Your assumption is that this should evaluate to something like 7.0 = 7. This is not a type issue, but a floating point issue. 7.0 is probably not exactly 7.0, but more something like 7.0000000000000000001 or 6.99999999999999999999 hence your comparison operator doesn't work as expected. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php (read the big red box)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Are you 100% sure those are the values in your variables? [This test](https://3v4l.org/sKDQP) doesn't give me the same results as you describe.

Comment: Ran a test now and ```7.0 >= floatval("7")``` returns `true`. You are advised to check the value of `$data['payments_client']['accumulated']` and confirm if it is actually holding a possible comparison value.


`print_r($data['payments_client']['accumulated']);
`

Comment: @ErisanOlasheni You cannot rely on a floating point value to be an exact value. It is always an approximation, probably a very accurate one, but still only an approximation.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes what I mean it to confirm if the variable is actually holding a possible comparison value, this is a variable we don't know the source and might have been holding anything!

Comment: @ErisanOlasheni Advicing afdi5 to check the value is actually '7.0' is the wrong advice. He should rewrite the comparison. Something like `abs(A - B) < 0.0000001` (this is just an example, the real solution depends on what the numbers represent and which comparison needs to be made).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware This is still not clear and not easy to understand, use an example to matches his use case.

Comment: @ErisanOlasheni OK, what about: `$data['payments_client']['accumulated'] >= $data['charge_limit']-1E-10`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191302/discussion-between-erisan-olasheni-and-kiko-software).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
$data['payments_client']['accumulated'] = 7.0;
$data['charge_limit'] = "7" ;
$data['can_redeem'] = $data['payments_client']['accumulated'] >= floatval($data['charge_limit']);
echo ($data['can_redeem']? 'True': 'False');
```

emulates your example, you will get the result as 'True' in this case as advised in the comments.

However, as a general rule it is safer to use:

```
$data['can_redeem'] = abs($data['payments_client']['accumulated']-floatval($data['charge_limit'])) < 0.0001;
```

as your conditional so that there is no risk of floating point issues. Note, you can change the '0.0001' to '0.01' or '0.000001' depending on your needs.

If you still get 'False' then you need to debug your code to check the values in $data['payments_client']['accumulated'] and in $data['charge_limit'].